# Wrong ELF class - PHP extension

Tags: php, c++, build, elf

I am trying to load a PHP extension (sdo.so) but I am getting the following error when I try to run XAMPP.

```
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/opt/lampp/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20060613/sdo.so' - /opt/lampp/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20060613/sdo.so: wrong ELF class: ELFCLASS64 in Unknown on line 0
```

From what I've seen other people say it seems to be something to do with it being compiled on a 64bit machine and it needs 32bit. Is this the root of the problem? If so how would I compile it as 32bit in Fedora 17 as I've only seen solutions for Ubuntu and couldn't get them to work for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> From what I've seen other people say it seems to be something to do with it being compiled on a 64bit machine

It doesn't matter *on* which machine you compile (the build host). What matters is *for* what machine you compile (the target host).

You are (apparently) running a 32-bit ix86 `PHP`, so you need to compile `sdo.so` for 32-bit ix86 as well.

> how would I compile it as 32bit in Fedora 17

```
./configure CC='gcc -m32' CXX='g++ -m32' && make && make install
```

should be about it.