# Unable to load dynamic library zip.so wrong ELF class: ELFCLASS32

Tags: php, debugging, zip, shared-libraries, warnings

I've installed a gamepanel on my Linux (CENTOS 6.7 x86_64) all worked fine but then i got a blank page and in the error_log I find this:

> PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library
>   '/usr/local/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20121212/zip.so' -
>   /usr/local/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20121212/zip.so: wrong
>   ELF class: ELFCLASS32 in Unknown on line 0

How can I resolve this error? I tried to put a "zip.so" file in extensions folder but that doesn't work.

Ok,  i think the problem is that i have x86 and my zip.so is for another version, how can i compile it for x86_64 then?

Comment: You have a 32bit version of zip.so most likely.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/16762892/2191572 and http://stackoverflow.com/q/12092913/2191572

Comment: I tryed to find another one but i can't find, any solution?